# how can i get Intersection by a key in nested array and then get all values from another key by previous key

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with three docs like this:

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    title: 1,
    set: [
      {
        pid: 'p1',
        vid: 'p1v1',
      },
      {
        pid: 'p2',
        vid: 'p2v1',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    title: 2,
    set: [
      {
        pid: 'p1',
        vid: 'p1v2',
      },
      {
        pid: 'p2',
        vid: 'p2v2',
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    title: 3,
    set: [
      {
        pid: 'p1',
        vid: 'p1v3',
      },
      {
        pid: 'p3',
        vid: 'p3v1',
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

A:
I can get all intersection `pid` from all three docs which is `'p1'` with the following aggregate:

```
[
  { $group: { _id: 0, pids: { $push: "$set.pid" } } },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      pids: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$pids",
          initialValue: { $arrayElemAt: ["$pids", 0] },
          in: { $setIntersection: ["$$this", "$$value"] },
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

B：
how can I get all the associated `vid` by the intersection `pid`?

in this case `pid` is `'p1'`, the `vid` will be `['p1v1', 'p1v2', 'p1v3']`

Comment: Can you post your expected output?

Comment: @TiyaJose i want get {pid:'p1', vids: ['p1v1','p1v2','p1v3'], <and all other intersection pairs>} Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$set"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "set.pid": "p1"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$set.pid",
      vids: {
        "$addToSet": "$set.vid"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You can also drop the `$match` stage and then you'll get the result for each `pid`.

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y9MttPzzy0C)

------------------------ EDIT ---------------------------------

With the requirement of `pid` appearing in all the docs:

(I recommend you pre-count the amount of documents in the collection so you could it in the aggregation)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$set"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$set.pid",
      vids: {
        "$addToSet": "$set.vid"
      },
      ids: {
        "$addToSet": "$_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          {
            $size: "$ids"
          },
          3
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      vids: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zfpwM0VQHJB)

If you don't want to pre-count the document count we'll have to add an initial `$group` stage to do so (meaning we will have to group the entire collection), I personally recommend against this but here's the code for it:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      roots: {
        "$addToSet": "$$ROOT"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$roots"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$roots.set"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$roots.set.pid",
      vids: {
        "$addToSet": "$roots.set.vid"
      },
      ids: {
        "$addToSet": "$roots._id"
      },
      docCount: {
        $first: "$count"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          {
            $size: "$ids"
          },
          "$docCount"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      vids: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aKrVvoGT3LW)

Comment: thanks for you answer, sorry for my poor english. id dont want specific `p1`, i expect all those `pid` and 'vid's pair.

Comment: then just remove the `$match` stage from the pipeline.

Comment: i get the expected result https://mongoplayground.net/p/CRXGLp-I3dn but it's ugly，maybe you can optimize it.

Comment: Can you explain why you dont have `p3` in your results? why is this not the required result? https://mongoplayground.net/p/QKYaaTLpJCj

Comment: because `p3` not in all three docs, i want all `pid` in all docs, and the get all associated `vids` with those `pid`